# How to move PDF files from a parent folder to a subfolder which has the same name as the file

Tags: javascript, pdf, drive

I am working on a project which sends PDFs from a Wordpress website to a Google Drive. The files are PDFs of people who registered for certain events, which are held in certain cities. These PDFs are all sent to a parent folder "registrations". What I need to achieve is to automatically send these PDFs to subfolders like Amsterdam, Rotterdam, Woerden, Westland etc.

The PDFs are all sent to a parent folder "registrations". What I need to achieve is to automatically send these PDFs to subfolders like Amsterdam, Rotterdam. The names of the PDFs are  the city names (e.g. Amsterdam).

In conclusion, the question basically is: how could I achieve to send a file with the name Amsterdam to a subfolder with the name Amsterdam, and a file with the name Rotterdam to a folder with the name Rotterdam?

**EDIT:**  I am working on the script, but it is not complete yet. The script below searches for files in a parent folder that contains "woerden" in its name. Next, it moves these files to a folder called "woerden". This works, but the problem is that I will have to create about 300 different scripts to be able to automate the entire process. I am therefore wondering if it is possible to make this script more dynamic. For example, if  a file with a name that contains -woerden- it is sent to a folder with the name woerden, and if a file with a name that contains -westland- it will be sent to a folder with the name westland.

```
    function SearchFiles() {

  // Parent folder
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('15azR1-Fic_F_wPZHzXWKblIyxBB_GVsW'); //parent folder which will be scanned for duplicates

  // Log the name of every file in the user's Drive whose name contains "westland".
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(
    'title contains "westland"');
while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();

  // Remove the file from all parent folders
  var parents = file.getParents();
  while (parents.hasNext()) {
    var parent = parents.next();
    parent.removeFile(file);
  }
  DriveApp.getFolderById('1mSW3-uqv_F1m-TfLa_JyGRVK9-sGJYTj').addFile(file);
}

}
```

I hope that I asked my question clearly. Please let me know if you need some more information.

Cheers,

Comment: Can you provide your current script? In your situation, Drive API is required to be used. So from your script, I would like to confirm the method for using Drive API.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I am working on the script, but it is very far from complete. Please check the script in the edited description.

Comment: Thank you for replying and the additional information. From your additional information, I could understand that you want to move a file to the folder of the same name with the file, and the number of files are 300. I cannot understand about the patterns of filenames of files like ``-woerden-`` and ``-westland-``. Can you provide all patterns of filenames and the folder names you want to use? I thought that because your script uses ``'title contains "westland"'`` for searching files, it is required to know all names. If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: By the way, you want to achieve your goal using Google Apps Script. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes I am indeed using Google Apps Script. Hope that's possible! To answer your question: there will be hundreds of files that are sent to a parent folder, and they have to be divided over about 300 childfolders. The names of the files are for example: Willem de Vries - Woerden - 15-09-2019, where - Woerden - is the city name, and thus the name of the folder where it should be moved to.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your question, ``-westland-`` and ``-woerden-`` are used. But in your comment, ``Willem de Vries - Woerden - 15-09-2019`` is used. Unfortunately, I'm not sure about other patterns. So for example, can you provide the regular expressions for the patterns of filenames?

Comment: The filenames are created by a Wordpress Plugin.They can be changed if that's needed. It basically is built up as following: First name last name - City - Date (dd-mm-yyyy). Hope this helps!